# CSS not being executed in Woocommerce Wordpress template file

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a fully functional Wordpress custom theme. I have just installed Woocommerce and followed [this guide](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/). I have followed the very basic instructions to copy `page.php`, rename it and modify the loop. I have done this and am able to use Woocommerce, however in the page.php file, I have a

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

command, which successfully displays that part of the layout in my normal wordpress pages. However, in the direct clone which is now called woocommerce.php, it is not working fully, The links show up, but without any of the associated css which is linked into the header file. Any ideas why two versions of the same file would mean only one correctly imports / interprets the css?

Here are the two web pages:

http://www.gas-sense.co.uk/blog
http://www.gas-sense.co.uk/blog/product/gas-sense-personal/

Comment: Which one is it? Is it not successfully loading the stylesheet? Or is it not successfully interpreting it? Does the <link> show up in the source when it's loaded?

Comment: Can you also provide a link to your site please? so that we can check. thanks

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is, but the HTML is coming across successfully and the css isn't working. I am testing locally, but could upload if you need it?

Comment: I've always found it much easier to customize `archive-product.php` in the theme's woocommerce folder (has to be created) than using a woocommerce page override. You don't have any if statements that would prevent CSS loading in the header do you?

Comment: This could be for a few different reasons. Is the css specific to a container that is not present? Or a body class?

Comment: There aren't any if statements and it shouldn't be a class definition thing, as the html is a clone, the only difference is the file name?

Comment: I have uploaded this to the web. www.gas-sense.co.uk/blog   vs. www.gas-sense.co.uk/blog/product/gas-sense-personal/

Comment: I agree with Aibrean. The simplest way to create a woocommerce page is to create a woocommerce folder, and just copy over the files from plugin templates folder, and chop away :D Either that or try adding html with hooks. When I create a theme I create a php file that has all the hooks to modify the woocommerce page. You can add wrappers, sidebars, etc. It takes a while, but it's possible. That way you're not touching the theme files or plugin files at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have fixed this now. It was a dreamweaver issue, when cloning the file and renaming it, dreamweaver didn't seem to catch up with updating the links. I have since manually rewritten the references and it is working, thank for your help!